# How to read a date and create a variable with value following day/time

Tags: shell, ubuntu, unix, gnu

Using GNU/Linux. Currently trying to read a date as input (yyyymmdd format) and create a variable which will hold value with next day date and a specific time - say 11am).
Any idea how to create it.

Tried with below, can it be altered for next day,

```
date —date=‘TZ=“EST” 09:00 next Fri’
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "Enter a date (yyyymmdd): " input_date
```

Calculate the next day's date :

```
next_day=$(date -d "$input_date + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
```

Combine the next day's date with the desired time

```
next_day_time="${next_day}110000"
```

Print the result to the console :

```
echo "Next day and time: $next_day_time"
```

Store the result in a variable :

```
next_day_var=$next_day_time

echo "Next day and time variable: $next_day_var"
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Is there a way to find date/time for next_day_var variable plus 13hours

Comment: Yes here is example next_day_plus_13h=$(date -d "${next_day} + 13 hours" "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

Comment: If you got solution then please approve the answer so other people can reach out to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that did not work for me - instead, I went with timezone for ease of use across regions in my case as below to get server time converted across regions:

sgp_time=$(TZ=Singapore date -d "$EST_time" +%s)